# Automapper mapping type with subtype

Tags: c#, automapper

I've got a case in which I need to map something like this:

```
public class Event
{
    string Name {get;set;}
    int EventType {get;set;}
    SubType Sub {get;set;}
}
```

The problem is that the way SubType inside should be mapped is determined by the `EventType` property of the `Event` class. For different types of events I want different things to be mapped.

The usual way is to create maps for both Event and SubType - they are not related to each other:

```
 map.CreateMap<EventDTO, Event>();
 map.CreateMap<SubTypeDTO, SubType>();
```

How can I tell automapper to change behaviour in the SubType mapping based on the `Event.EventType`?

PS> I know this is bad design and it really should be resolved by refactoring the whole thing ( eg. removing the EventType and creating subclasses )
Unfortunately I inherited this code and just need to resolve bugs without spending to much time.

Comment: Hi, I'm running into the same issue. One property that tells what subtype to map to, and the other property that is the BASE type. Automapper always maps the base class and not the subclass. How did you solve this using ResolveUsing? I'd appreciate if you could tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Hey! I know it's been over a year and you ended up fixing it differently, but could you mark my response as the answer to your question? I kinda need the points ☺
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there's something to achieve this, but you could do the following:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<EventDTO, Event>()
            .ForMember(to => to.Name, from => from.Ignore() )
            .ForMember(to => to.Sub, from => from.Ignore() )
            .ForMember(to => to.EventType, from => from.Ignore() )
            .AfterMap((source, dest) =>
                          {
                              switch (dest.EventType)
                              {
                                  case 1:
                                      // Behaviour EventType 1
                                      ...
                                      dest.Name = source.NameDTO + "1";
                                      ...
                                      break;
                                  case 2:
                                      // Behaviour EventType 2
                                      ...
                                      dest.Name = source.NameDTO + "2";
                                      ...
                                      break;
                                  default:
                                      // Behaviour EventType 3
                                      ...
                                      dest.Name = source.NameDTO + "0";
                                      ...
                                      break;
                              }
                          });
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution although I have already solved this issue: using the `ResolveUsing<>()` and by creating a custom resolver. It has access to the parent entity as well as the child one.